# onFocus and onBlur doesnt work , react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, native, android-tv

I'm trying to build an androidTV application with react-native and i followed the documents , but whatever i do , it seems like onFocus and onBlur wont work for me , here's the code:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableHighlight
        hasTVPreferredFocus={true}
        accessible={true}
        onFocus={() => alert('focus')}
        onBlur={() => alert('blur')}
        onPress={() => alert('press')}>
        <Text>This is a text</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <Button title="title" />
    </View>
  );
};
```

i also added the `hasTVPreferredFocus` and `accessible` to make sure i didnt miss anything .

Comment: `import {TouchableHighlight,Button} from "react-native";` Use this line and it will works fine with you.

Comment: @MohamedBdr i already have them imported , the component themselves work fine , but the props {onBlur , onFocus} are the problem

Comment: Can you please tell me what you want to do, so If you clicked on `This is a text` you will find the alert on press so is that what you want or you want to Button to do this behavior?

Comment: @MohamedBdr i want to detect when the component is Focused and when it goes out of Focus , so with that i`d be able to change the styling when the user moves around with D-pad on androidTv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to fix it , it seems like `npx react-native init <ProjectName>` is not complete and has some missing files in it.
instead i used `react-native init <ProjectName> --template=react-native-tvos` and it worked ! i think the tvos version is better to run for tv development.

Comment: What is the actual code difference? I want to know so I can put that into my project...

Answer (score 0):

it does not work because that component does not listen those events, check the documentation:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight

Comment: in the doc it doesnt show "onPress" as the props but it works . also here https://github.com/dev-seb/react-native-tv-demo/blob/master/src/components/focusable/FocusableHighlight.js this dude used onFocus and onBlur on a touchablehighlight

Comment: Yea but it is a "Touchable", it's kind of obvious tha will be a pressable component, in the example they use it..

Comment: [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/building-for-tv#code-changes) , it says we can use onFocus and onBlur on touchable mixins. also in vs-code it suggests onBlur and onFocus only on touchable mixins which is another reason to harden the fact that we CAN use said props

Comment: And here we are, thinking about this fail.. if you havent, try using useRef() hook to send focus from another event..

Comment: It does have the onFocus and onBlur props, and the documentations says so, it's just not listed here but in TouchableWithoutFeedback, and the docs says that touchableHighlight inherits TouchableWithoutFeedback Props.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { styles } from './styles';

const Input = (props) => {
  const [focused, setFocused] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <TextInput
      {...props}
      onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
      onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
      style={focused ? styles.inputFocused : styles.input}
    />
  );
};

export default Input;
```

If your props override onFocus function just bring it on the head like this

Comment: i want to use onFocus and onBlur on `<TouchableHighlight>` or any other touchable mixin